# InfoPath Form to Auto Populate User Data

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, infopath

How to Create an InfoPath Form to Auto Populate User Data (User name, User Email, Manger Name etc) in SHAREPOINT SERVER ENTERPRISE SITE (Online). Do we need Central Admin Settings for the same?

Answer (score 0):

We can can populate the user fields in InfoPath form via userprofileservice data connection.

Steps:

1.With InfoPath opened go to Tools > Data Connections, and click 'add…' to add a new data connection to the form. This opens up the Data Connection Wizard.

2.We want to receive data from the WS about the current user, so choose receive data' and click next.

3.Our data source is a WS so choose 'Web Service' and next.

4.Now you will have to point the wizard to the WS. Type an address similar to this: **http://ServerName/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx**  and click next.

5.Here you get a list of all methods for that WS, choose **GetUserProfileByName** and click next.

6.In this screen you can specify what parameters are sent to the method, we are relying on the method's ability to return the current user name if no value is passed to it, so we will leave this as is (no value is passed to the method) and click next.

7.Click next and make sure 'Automatically retrieve data when form is opened' is checked.

8.Finish the wizard.

References:
[Auto Populate User Information in InfoPath with Claims Based Authentication in SharePoint](https://spvee.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/auto-populate-user-information-in-infopath-with-claims-based-authentication-part-1-of-3/)